# Working of the picturebox

Tags: c#

How can I transfer the `picturebox` image in `form 1` to another `pictureboxbox` of `form2` in `C#.net`? Same goes with the label. Its working in the same form, but not in different forms.
Can anyone help me out with this.

I have made the picture box of form2 as public. if i want to transfer it to the picture box of form2 from form1 (firstpicturebox : name of picturebox in form1),

```
form2 frm2=new form2();
frm2.picturebox1.image=firstpicturebox.image;
```

It's not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating a new instance of Form2 rather than using the existing one.

Try something like:

```
// in form1
            PictureBox picBox = (PictureBox)Form2.InstanceOfForm.Controls["pictureBox1"];
        picBox.Image = this.firstpicturebox.Image;
// in form2
public static Form InstanceOfForm;
...
// in Form2_Load()
InstanceOfForm = this;
```

Comment: I am not able to use the picturebox1 when I am writing form2.instanceofform.picturebox1.image.

Comment: What are the pictureboxes on Form1 and Form2 called?

Comment: form1 picturebox is firstpicturebox.

Comment: form2 picturebox is picturebox1.

Comment: I made both of them as public

Comment: OK, I've changed my answer. Change Form1 code to form2.InstanceOfForm.picturebox1.image = this.firstpicturebox.Image;

Comment: But i am not able to access the picturebox1 when I am writing the leht hand side of the statement

Comment: no..Now I couldn't access controls  (Instanceofform.controls)